# Поиск строк нужного размера findstr windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

```
findstr /r "^.{200,}"  C:\Users\user\txt
```

нужно извлечь из файла "txt", строки > 200 символов

кто подскажет почему не работает такой код?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 0):

[`findstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) не поддерживает фигурные скобки и много чего ещё из стандартных регулярных выражений.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/904920)

Comment: @Глеб - Является ответом!  В вопросе спрашивалось почему не работает код.  Там не спрашивалось больше ничего другого (напр, как сделать чтобы он заработал).

Comment: Извиняюсь, если так. Сильно походе на стандартный однострочник-комментарий. надо было внимательнее...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы в файле найти строки более 200 символов, можно выполнить powershell :

```
Get-Content .\имя_файла.txt |Select-String '.{200,}'
```